# Polymorphism vs regular inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I use polymorphism so frequently, but it suddenly dawned upon me. I have the case where my code is:

```
class A{

class B : public A{

class C : public A{
```

and I use class `A` as a polymorphic parameter type for passing in `B` or `C` sub types:

```
//Accepts B and C objects
void aMethod(A* a){
```

However, I gave `A` a virtual destructor- this is the only reason A (and B and C) contain a vtable pointer.

So my question is, if I hadn't declared A with a virtual destructor, then A wouldn't be polymorphic- I wouldn't be able to pass objects of type B or C in `aMethod()`??

So is non-polymorphic inheritance just about sharing code, whereas polymorphism (the base class must have a vtable) allows passing sub types as arguments of the base class type?

Comment: `void aMethod` takes an object of type `A`? You would need it to take a pointer or a reference for polymorphism to kick in. Otherwise, you are just slicing `B` and `C` objects.

Comment: If your parameter is passed by value like in your example, your objects will be sliced.

Comment: this could have been a good question 10 years ago, A) there are other and better ways to achieve polymorphic behaviour B) your title doesn't reflect the question C) inheritance is about the _is a_ relationship/property - however you wanna call it - at its own core, the `virtual` keywords doesn't change that, it only adds on the polymorphism side .

Answer (score 2):

In this code you provide,

```
void aMethod(A a){
```

the `a` formal argument is not polymorphic. It's passed by value. When you pass in a `B` or `C` object as actual argument, you're just **slicing** it down to an `A`, that is, you're copying the `A` base class sub-object only.

---

Regarding

> **”** So is non-polymorphic inheritance just about sharing code, whereas polymorphism (the base class must have a vtable) allows passing sub types as arguments of the base class type?

it combines two questions that have to be treated separately.

Inheriting from a non-polymorphic class is about sharing of code, yes, but it also introduces an *is-a* relationship, which can be important for e.g. passing by reference.

Inheriting from a polymorphic class (one with one or more virtual member functions) allows you to *override* base class functionality, or to implement it where the base class leaves that as a derived class responsibility – typically by having pure virtual member functions. This means that member functions in the base class can call your derived class’ member functions. Also, that calling member functions via a base class pointer or reference, can call your derived class’s implementations.

Comment: Ok but what I have described doesn't require any overriding. I have a normal inheritance hierarchy where the base class has a virtual destructor..... if I remove the virtual dtor- its normal inheritance. Does that mean aMethod() wouldn't work any more?

Comment: @user997112: As regards `aMethod` you can just make the destructor non-virtual, or remove it wholly if it doesn't do anything. But that doesn't save you much, really. It has the flavor of a premature optimization. The general advice for optimization is to **measure**, to discover whether you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Non-polymorphic types also contain a subobject for each base class, and upcasts are still implicit.

You can therefore pass objects of derived classes just fine even when there is no polymorphism.  The receiver will act on the base subobject, just as happens for data members and non-virtual functions of polymorphic types.

Answer (score 0):

A class with its destructor the only `virtual` method, like your `class A`, is an oddity. AFAIK, such a class has no necessity in well designed code.

From your question, it is not clear whether the `virtual` destructor is needed (i.e. if you ever call the destructor of classes `B` or `C` through a reference or pointer to class `A`), but if it is, your code smells. If it is not, then simply make the destructor non-virtual.

Comment: A virtual desctructor is needed for inheritance, or else objects would be sliced in destruction (e.g, if you call `C * c = new C(); A * a = c; delete a`, A destructor would be called, not C).

Comment: @Leonardo I know (as you would have notived had you read my answer fully). But a class like this without any other `virtual` methods has hardly any usage.